# Confused by object property output

Tags: javascript, object

I'm fairly new to programming and studying JavaScript and trying to understand objects and property names.  In the following  example (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), the lesson states that this code (below) outputs "value", since both foo and bar are converted to the same string. I understand that a property must be a string and that a number will automatically be typed as a string, but I don't understand why both foo and bar resolve to 'value'. To me it seems like the last line of code should resolve to '2' since var bar = 2.  What am I missing?  Thank you!

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
object[foo] = 'value';
console.log(object[bar]);
```

Comment: The key can't be an object. What happens is that the object will get stringified, and you end up with `{'[object Object]': 'value'}`

Comment: @elclanrs: well, objects _can_ be keys, as we see above, but that's not what's needed because all data objects will produce the same key.

Comment: you might want `object[foo.unique_prop]`

Comment: Just try it out by doing `console.log(foo.toString());` and `console.log(bar.toString());` this will give you the same string `'[object Object]'`. So `object{'[object Object]': 'value'}` will be the result.

Comment: Worth noting that in ECMA-262 ed 6  there are [*computed property names*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and also [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects that allow Objects as keys.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that a property must be a string and that a number will
>   automatically be typed as a string

Yes, the key must be a string. If it isn't, then anything you pass will be converted to a string, including objects. You can read what you wrote as:

```
object[foo.toString()] = 'value'
```

An object stringified gives you `'[object Object]'`. So in effect, you would be adding and retrieving the same key:

```
{'[object Object]': 'value'}
```

Comment: I"m sorry, I am not following.  I even asked a couple of coworkers who do scripting in other languages and they don't follow either. When I type the code in Codepen, nothing happens.  Firstly, when I look at the last line, I don't understand why (object[bar]) does not resolve to (object['2']). Secondly, I don't understand how line two and three are connected at all.  Line two is talking about foo.  Line three is talking about bar. Line three is where the action happens, right?

Comment: @HollyFortenberry: Two different objects resolve to the **same** string: `'[object Object]'`. So it is the same key. See? http://jsfiddle.net/Lhwm4g0f/. Why do you expect `object[bar]` to resolve to `object['2']`? That's the point of confusion; it resolves to `object['[object Object]']`

Comment: The reason I think it resolves to object['2'] is because I see in the first line that var bar is assigned to {unique_prop: 2}.  So that number 2 should get converted to a string, '2'. I'm sorry if I'm missing something really basic.  I'm very new to this.  I feel dumb.

Comment: But that number 2 is the value of a key. What happens to the key? What happens is the **whole** object gets stringified, not just some random property of it. If you were to do `var bar = 2; object[bar] = 'value'`, then you'd get `object === {'2': 'value'}`

Comment: Thank you elclanrs. I checked out the jsfiddle and I see you wrote in the third line as console.log(object);.  I'm confused about why the object inside the console.log parentheses is being changed from bar to object. I think that's the crux of what I'm not understanding.

Comment: I was typing same time as you and didn't see your last response until I just hit enter on mine after it.  I'll go back and read what you said. I think you have hit on my gap in understanding, keys!  Thank you !